# Swift switch statement not covering all cases

Tags: swift, swiftui, switch-statement

My desired outcome is to cover values and ranges between 0% and 100%, but my progress view works with values of 0.0 to 1.0 where 1.0 equal 100%

Can someone point me to the right direction?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProgressBar: View {
    @Binding var progress: Double
    var color: Color
    
    init(progress: Binding<Double>) {
        _progress = progress
        switch progress.wrappedValue {
        case 0.0...0.20: // Fix: on 0.206 I get black color value
            color = .green
            
        case 0.21...0.40:
            color = .green
            
        case 0.41...0.60:
            color = .yellow
            
        case 0.61...1.0:
            color = .red
            
        default:
            color = .black
        }
    }
```

Comment: make case like this ```case 0.0..<0.21:``` and ```case 0.21..<0.41:```.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, your cases don't cover all of the numerical possibilities. Also, your `color` should likely be a computed property based on the current state of the `Binding`, rather than something you set in `init`:

```
struct ProgressBar: View {
    @Binding var progress: Double
    var color: Color {
        switch progress {
        case 0.0..<0.20:
            return .blue
        case 0.20..<0.40:
            return .green
        case 0.40..<0.60:
            return .yellow
        case 0.60...1.0:
            return .red
        default:
            return .black
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        color
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code fixed my missed cases and now is more elegant using computed properties.